# Send a message in discord channel with POST request with undici

Tags: javascript, typescript, post, discord, undici

I'm trying to understand how the Discord API works, and I'm struggling to send a message in a channel. the code executes fine, but the message is not being sent. I tried with this code:

```
await request(`https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/${channel_id}/messages`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: content,
    headers: this.headers,
  });
```

but it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong? 
`content` is the string I want to send, it's a function parameter and so is `channel_id`.

headers is:

```
{
  authorization: `Bot ${token}`,
  accept: "*/*",
};
```

The request returns a status code of `400` (Bad request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The issue is that I didn't specify the `Content-Type` of the request, and passed the content as a string. I added to the `headers`: `"content-type": "application/json"`, and to the body I passed a Json object of the content:

```
await request(`https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/${channel_id}/messages`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: this.headers,
    body: json({ content }),
  });
```

And the headers:

```
this.headers = {
      authorization: `Bot ${token}`,
      "content-type": "application/json",
    };
```